# Outlook Reading Area - Remove Calendar, but keep next appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to remove the calendar (red square) from the tasks-view in the reading pane, so that there is more space for the upcoming appointments (green square)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove the calendar (red square) from the tasks-view in the reading pane, so that there is more space for the upcoming appointments (green square)?

**No.**

As i know, to always be able to see your upcoming items, we need to dock the Calendar peek to the Outlook window. Whether in the Task view or any other view, once we cancel docking the Calendar peek, the upcoming appointment will disappear with it.

Comment: I think you are right. :(

Comment: Glad to help you!  Would you mind marking my reply as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.